# libgdx HTML5 deployment

Tags: html, eclipse, gwt, deployment, libgdx

I've been working with `libgdx` for 2 days, and I'm starting to get the hang of it.
I'm comfortable with deployment on Android and desktop, but I've got no clue about how to run/debug or deploy the `HTML5` version.
When I run as web application, the link gives me an `http error 404`.
I did what they say on the libgdx wiki, but that ain't working, so, help would be welcome.
BTW, the app's working fine on Android and desktop.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

In Eclipse -- right click on the `*-html` project.  Select "Google" -> "GWT Compile". This will perform a GWT compile on the project, it can take a while so be patient. Once this is completed, I was able to copy the expanded `war` directory into my tomcat `webapps` directory. Tomcat was already running, it picked up the change and deployed the game, I was able to load it via `localhost:8080/war/` I later renamed the directory (the one in the webapps folder) to something more appropriate for my project.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem for over an hour before realizing that when I selected "run as web application" and eclipse asked me to point to the war directory, I was silly enough to have been selecting the root directory of the project.

Once I went back and pointed to the actual war folder, it ran without issue. Silly I know, but might not be a bad idea to check, esp if anyone is setting this up at 1 am like I am lol.

Answer (score 2):

According to the current date (December 2014), Libgdx now uses gradle and deploying using the mikeys's answer might not work for you. Follow the following guide for the best solution for this problem:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to deploy the app correctly. In the wiki of Libgdx (in google code) you can find in one of the first entries how to deploy and debug the app. The easiest way is to install and configure a Tomcat server, do the steps of the wiki and that's all. If you don't want deploy the app, only test it, you can do it directly from eclipse with the embedded server jetty included on the GWT Sdk. Hope this helps you.